# Unable to See the my custom-made Windows Service in Services

Tags: c#, windows-services, c#-2.0

I am currently developing a Custom made windows service using the .NET 2.0 Framework. I have used the InstallerUtil.exe and it installs perfectly(according to the Log from command prompt). But, thing is, I am unable to find it under Windows Services. I ran previous custom made services using 4.0 framework on my PC and it ran just fine. Note that I ddnt put any code in the service yet. I just need to make it start once it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of problems like this with InstallUtil.

Try using the command line `sc` program:

```
sc create "service name" binPath= "full path to service exe" start= auto
```

Just take care with the spaces in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Be Sure you have Added the Project Installer and follow the guidelines on 
this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28VS.80%29.aspx